# "Reset System", bootloop after attempting to dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I was trying to dual boot Ubuntu 21.04 with windows 10 on my
HP elitebook-folio-9480m.

I was following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/-iSAyiicyQY) to do the same.
After creating the partitions for the installation process. The system gave me a "fatal error" about some issues regarding the boot partition as far as i remember.

However in another window it said that the installation was complete and I needed to restart the computer.

As I did so my pc would boot-up, show the "hp" logo then show a message in the top left saying "Reset System" and repeat.

I have tried and enter the boot menu but to no avail.

Comment: Right at the beginning of the video the person states "for Legacy BIOS users". That is unlikely to be the case for any computer with preinstalled Windows since a decade ago. The undisclosed fatal error is very likely the consequences of not having/not selecting the ESP (EFI System Partition). Please follow proper guides like this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi instead of YT videos.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> repeatedly to enter the advanced reboot screen of Windows. After that:

1. enter into the BIOS
2. change the bios order
3. boot into Windows
4. delete the partition with the corrupted OS
5. remove grub.

Comment: Hello. You can not enter a computer BIOS through Windows. You enter BIOS by using the correct key on computer start. Your answer is completely wrong.

Comment: @David *Technically*, you can. Shift-clicking the Restart option in Windows 10 reboots into Windows's advanced startup settings, which has an option to reboot into UEFI/BIOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html) to locally boot Windows and Linux using <kbd>F2</kbd> in the menu for searching the GRUB file and boot for booting in to Linux.