# Stuck at bootloop after dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

**Situation**: I'm stuck at a boot loop after trying to set up a dual boot on my Thinkpad 470 using a Rufus bootable pen drive and Ubuntu desktop LTS.

**Goal**: Be able to boot windows.

**Details**: I have a very similar issue to this guy here ["Reset System", bootloop after attempting to dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379335/reset-system-bootloop-after-attempting-to-dual-boot) although I wasn`t following the  same tutorial. After finishing the installation I got a fatal error message and when I tried to restart my computer it would show "Reset system" on the top left corner and restart the computer in a loop.

I tried the boot repair tool, but it didn't work. I went back on the try Ubuntu and runned some commands from other posts.

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` gave me this: N1QET92W (1.67 )

`sudo update-grub` gave me this: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.

I also runned `sudo fdisk -l` and saved the result, I can paste it here if needed.

I went on the Bios to change the boot order several times, but Ubuntu would always stay at the top, even after changing it to the bottom or even deleting it. So, I went on GParted and completely deleted all the partitions that I made for Ubuntu. The "reset system" loop stopped after doing this but now I am seeing a boot menu with two options, *ATA HDD0 : ST500LM021-1KJ152* and *PCI LAN*, if I select one them the screen goes black for a moment but then the menu reappears, in a loop.

If I'm using the default settings on the BIOS(UEFI), I go straight up to this boot menu, but if I'm using Legacy Mode, I'll first see a screen saying "Intel Boot agent" and *Initializing and establishing link* below. Then it will show *PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cables* and *PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent* and then it will show the same boot menu.

Thanks in advance for any help, if there's any command that I should run, picture or information that could help just let me know.

Comment: Finally solved the issue using rescatux https://youtu.be/dGA8e_A2PeA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a usb-stick with Ikki Boot ( around 2.6 GB ) or super_grub2_disk_hybrid ( around 20 Mb ) on another computer. In Ikki Boot use the super_grub2_disk_hybrid program. It will search your harddisk for all bootable operating systems and you can boot into them. 
Once booted into Windows you can repair the bootloader. 
Ikki Boot also has repair programs for bootloaders ( I have not explored it enough to advise you which program to use and how to use that ), but I think that doing it from Windows itself should be better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I managed to boot into windows. Would you know how I should proceed to fix the bootloader?

Comment: Even though I have a triple boot system ( Kubuntu 20.04.2, mint 20.3 and Win 10 ) I can't remember when I used Windows. There is a program EasyBCD that can do that in Windows. There should also be a program inside standard Windows but you better ask Dr. Google. Would you please accept the answer, so other users can see that the problem is solved. ( You booted into Windows, but still haven´t got the dual boot working (which was not the question))

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot anyway. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks for accepting the answer.